# How do I enable automated replies to users with Weavy?

Tags: weavy

I want to enable automated replies with the help of Weavy. Automated replies with the help of a bot is helpful when someone text another user who is offline at that moment. Adding that feature to an end-user will help giving an idea of expectation to the user asking the question in a chat.

I searched the Weavy doc but didn't find any articles related to chat bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a [webhook](https://www.weavy.com/docs/learn/webhooks) that is triggered when a message is created.

After you recieve the event in your application you can use the Weavy API to insert a message in the conversation or whatever you would like to do.